# Terraform Associate Public IP with auto generated node_resource_group

Tags: terraform, azure-aks, terraform-provider-azure

I am working on getting an AKS cluster up using terraform and have built a public ip with everything I want in it but I can't seem to find a good way to associate it with the node_resource_group that is auto generated by the AKS cluster. I need is as a frontend ip configuraton. Does anyone know how to do this with Terraform?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the following block in your AKS resource definition to configure the first front-end public IP of your Standard Load Balancer:

https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/kubernetes_cluster.html#load_balancer_profile

and set the `outbound_ip_address_ids` to match your PIP id

https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/kubernetes_cluster.html#outbound_ip_address_ids